# How do I use a GraphicsView within a ScrollView to show a window of text from a large file?

Tags: graphics, scrollview, maui

I am trying to write a readonly text viewer.

I cannot discover from the docs how I might paint with DrawString() 30 or 40 lines or whatever fits in the current window height on to a GraphicsView from the *current* line in the file and then use the ScrollView to change that current line to, say, 50 000 lines down and draw the data at that point.

It feels like I have to wire up the ScrollView to understand that the GraphicsView needs to be (virtually) way bigger than it is, and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: As an alternative, you may use a  [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0) with label in it.

Comment: CollectionView supports incremental data virtualization as the user scrolls. [Load data incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0#load-data-incrementally)